# Reload config table in running Go program

Tags: arrays, http, go, reload

I have a web server that has multiple HTTP handler wrapper. One of them is ACL which is loaded from a CSV as a struct array and passed to the ACL HTTP hander. I wanted to be able to change the  csv file to update new filter entries without restarting the web server.

I tried adding flag and then calling it with a boolean that removes the array and reload it by calling the new csv file. But that doesn't really work, its not calling the existing array table that is within the running process.

What is the best way to achieve this? This is my program structure, I'm just trying to avoid restarting the web server whenever I have to update the ACL. I could use a separate Key Value database but at this stage I have to keep it simple as the server does not belongs to me.

```
func main() {
    ACL := aclGroup()
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler:        aclAction(logRequestHandler(mux), ACL),
        Addr:           listen,
        ReadTimeout:    5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:    5 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }

...
}

func aclAction(h http.Handler, acl []*ACLlist) http.Handler {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pass `aclAction` a function that will return the current `ACLList` instead of passing in the `ACLList` itself. Whenever a handler needs the list it should call the function to get it. Doing this makes it relatively simple to implement code that updates the list (but make sure it's thread safe!) and the new list will be returned when it is next requested.

Here is a simple (somewhat contrived and simplified) example; try it in [the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/skfAuT7ane6):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ACLlist struct {
    text string
}


// For now the ACL List is stored in a global variable; the true structure is likely to be a bit more complex
var currentList []ACLlist
var mu sync.Mutex

func main() {
    currentList = []ACLlist{{"one"}}
    go aclAction(aclGroup)
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) // Give go routine time to get one value

    // Lets update the list (in reality this may run on a timer or you might watch a file)
    mu.Lock() 
    currentList = []ACLlist{{"one"}, {"two"}}
    mu.Unlock()

    // Give the go routine time to request the list again
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
}

// aclGroup returns the current ACL List
func aclGroup() []ACLlist {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()
    return currentList
}

// aclAction - accepts a function which will be called when the current ACL list is needed
func aclAction(getACL func() []ACLlist) {
    fmt.Printf("First call: %#v\n", getACL())
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Printf("Second Call: %#v]\n", getACL())
}
```

*note*: A tider approach would be to create an `ACLListManager` struct with functionality to manage the updates and a getter method that you pass to `aclAction` but this would have complicated the sample code.

Comment: Thanks Brits!! My initial code does somewhat similar to what you say, aclAction handler calls another function that loads ACLlist (which calls another function to load a local csv file). Too many reads, each request will trigger a file read which I thought is not efficient. I think I get your point, let me rework and try the revise idea.

Comment: You don't need to read the file every time; I generally start a go routine that reads it from time-to-time (e.g. every 10 minutes). An alternative is to store the time the config was read and when a new request comes in check if it is too old and grab a new copy if needed (be careful because another request may come in while you are refreshing it so use `sync.Once` or similar).

Comment: Thanks Brits. I rework the config by passing a pointer &ACL of the array into the handler. I realise in GO, when you pass an array as parameter to a function, it is not being referenced. I then create a func that updates the array and have a hook that I can called via web which will trigger the array to be reloaded. This way, a reload only when the csv is updated and manually trigger. Thanks for bouncing all the ideas, couldn't have get it to work without the ideas.

Comment: No worries; note that you do need to be a bit careful to ensure you don't end up with a race (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116224/go-concurrent-access-to-pointers-methods)).

Comment: ah ... thanks for pointing this out, very helpful and timely info!!